# Ruby on Rails - How to make one form action create two entries in differents tables

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, controller

Im creating a match, that contains maps (you can see in the 5th line)

```
<%= form_for(@match) do |f| %>
    <%= f.datetime_select :time %> </div>
    <%= f.collection_select(:event_id, Event.all, :id, :name) %>
    <%= f.number_field :best_of, min: 1, :style => "width: 50px;", :class => "bo-input" %>
    <%= collection_select(:round, :map_id, Map.all, :id, :display_name) %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Investigate `fields_for`, and possible `accepts_nested_attributes_for`

Comment: What is the relation between these models?

Comment: Using `accepts_nested_attributes_for` works great. The only problem is to add new scores in the client side using javascript, because `fields_for` name the fields with `[0]`, `[1]`, etc.

Comment: @lcguida Match: `has_many :scores` and Score: `belongs_to :match`

Comment: You want to render a form with rails and then add more forms with javascript, is that it? PS: I see `Event` and `Map` in your `@match` form. Where is this `Score` model?